# Spring Boot log file not being created

Tags: spring-boot, logging

I have a spring boot app (1.5.10.RELEASE) that logs great when running as a standalone application in Eclipse IDE.  I am using spring config and the properties file says this:

```
logging.level.com.myco.impl=DEBUG
logging.path=/log/myService
```

When I run as a standalone application, I see everything I see logged to the console and to a file in the above directory (called spring.log).

I then build my "uber jar" and run in like this:

java -jar my-service-0.1.0.jar.  I see all the console logging just like running in IDE.  I can see it looking for my configuration in spring config but I do not see any log file created.

I could use some ideas on what to look at.

Comment: Are there proper permissions on logging.path? Does the directory exists at all?

Answer (score 2):

In short - I (almost :-) ) believe that you have not set proper permissions on the logging path as pointed in the comments. The logging configurations seem quite simple and are described [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-logging.html#boot-features-logging-file-output). You can't get these wrong easily and yours seem OK.

The tricky part is how to diagnose the exact problem. For example on my system if I change the owner of the logging directory I can reproduce the behaviour with the uber jar that you described.

Next - I guess we both use `slf4j` with `logback` (e.g. coming because of `spring-boot-starter`). The laziest and quickest approach to understand what's wrong is to print the `logback` status messages as explained [here](https://logback.qos.ch/manual/configuration.html). For example - programatically - there are other options too but I'll take the dirtiest :-) . Put this somewhere in your code:

```
LoggerContext lc = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
// print logback's internal status
StatusPrinter.print(lc);

LOGGER.debug("Some other message");
```

If I do that in my sample app (boot 1.5.10.RELEASE) I can immediately see the problem printed in the console along with many more status messages:

```
23:23:07,857 |-ERROR in ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[FILE] - openFile(/tmp/so/spring.log,true) call failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/so/spring.log (Permission denied)
    at java.io.FileNotFoundException: /tmp/so/spring.log (Permission denied)
```

Comment: Thanks @Lachezar Belev.  I added the code above.  interesting enough when I am running outside an IDE, it is looking for logback.xml and not finding it.  This should be fine as I want my configuration with property files entries (so we can change it on the fly in config server).  But it does not seem to honor the property file settings coming from the config server.  It does when running in IDE though.  I do not see those messages (Could NOT find resource [logback.xml]) at all when running in IDE.  Weird?

Comment: Have you set-up somehow environment variables in your IDE run configurations, e.g. LOGGING_CONFIG?  Perhaps you can print the environment variables and logging props from within the application (inside and outside the IDE) and compare them? Integrating with spring cloud certainly makes difference since I've tried all properties in a single app and they work as expected... Or you can update the question with more details...

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I figured it out but it took me a few hours of downloading source code to understand the difference.  The problem was I started with a maven generated project and that is what I was running in my IDE.  I then created the gradle version using the intializer.  When I created the gradle version, I selected cloud config client but NOT cloud bootstrap.  It mostly worked except for this logging thing.  Turns out there was a class inside of cloud bootstrap that sets the logger again if using cloud config.

Comment: Just a little more information.  The class that was reiniatilizing was PropertySourceBootstrapConfiguration in org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.config.  Line in particular was   reinitializeLoggingSystem(environment, logConfig, logFile);

Comment: @LachezarBalev thank you for this comment! I had exactly same issue with permission denied. Too bad you need to add extra code to see error...
Anyway, to fix permission denied just add `chmod o+w file_name` and it should be good

Answer (score 0):

See comments above.  I did not include a jar I needed that was critical for reinitializing the logging system once it contacted spring cloud.

Answer (score 0):

The issue may be a bug in Spring Boot 1.5.10, see:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/11951
I've faced similar issue when application cannot run, because log file was owned by root user and not available to change by application user.
Try to upgrade Spring Boot to 1.5.11 -- issue fixed in this version.